# doctrine flush a single entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The doctrine interface `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` defines the `flush` method as having no parameters. Yet the implementation `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` allows a single entity to be passed.

Aside from the, IMO, bad programming style, Is this anything I need to be worried about?

I know that PHP will ignore any extra parameters if they are not declared in the method. Which would cause a non ORM manager to flush all entities.

I ask because I'm trying to write my code in such a way that the ORM is configurable and can switched at a later date. Now, while writing a batch import class, I have found that calling `flush` without an entity causes memory leaks, it also effects a 'progress/history' entity I use outside of the main import loop. So it's pretty important I only flush certain entities.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the differences between the definition and implementation of `flush()` as well. That may be a question only the developers of doctrine can answer.

### Short Answer

Don't worry about it.

### Long Answer

We can still address the differences and how they affect your application.

According to doctrine's documentation, `flush()` is the only method that will persist changes to your domain objects.
Other methods, such as `persist()` and `remove()` only place that object in a queue to be updated.

> It is very important to understand that only EntityManager#flush() ever causes write operations against the database to be executed. Any other methods such as EntityManager#persist($entity) or EntityManager#remove($entity) only notify the UnitOfWork to perform these operations during flush.
>   Not calling EntityManager#flush() will lead to all changes during that request being lost.

### Performance

Flushing individual entities at a time may cause performance issues in itself. Each `flush()` is a new trip to the database. Large sums of calls to `flush()` may slow down your application.

The `flush()` method *should not* be affecting your progress/history entity unless you are intentionally making changes to it. **But**, if that is the case, and you still do not want progress/history entity to be updated when `flush()` is executed, you can [detach the entity](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) from doctrine. This will allow you to make changes to the entity without doctrine being aware of those changes. Therefore, it will not be affected by `flush()`.

When you are ready for the entity to be re-attached to doctrine, you can use [the merge method](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) provided by your entity manager. Then call `flush()` one last time to merge the changes.